# I need a formula in my excel to check multiple criteria and give result in 3 ways

Tags: excel, multiple-columns

Actually, In my excel sheet i want to check when both values and print result example: I need answer like this 1 0 =1, 0 1 =1, 1 1 =0 How to write formula for this please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your conditions your formula in the resultant cell should be as follows

Conditions

```
1 0 = 1
0 1 = 1
1 1 = 1
```

Formula in resultant cell (can be extended to any other combinations of conditions and not using `XOR` as 0 0 condition is not defined)

```
=IF(OR(A1=0,B1=0), 1, 0)
```

Sample Excel Sheet
[image]

Comment: Thanks you and another one is If function always give the false value when I select Index and Match cell. That means Index and match formula gives a result is 1 and then i use the if condition on that cell like If(cell=1,0,1) then i gives false answer 1 instead of 0. Please help for this condition.

Comment: If the above answer solved your first question then please accept the answer by clicking check-mark on my answer and vote up by increasing 0 to 1 on the answer :). Regarding your second question, can you give example as I am not following your second question.